# Obtain bundle identifier programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, bundle-identifier

How can I get the bundle ID in Swift?

Objective-C version:

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Try this:

```
let bundleID = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
```

Swift 3+:

```
let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

Comment: Do you know why `bundleIdentifier` is an optional? In what cases can it be `nil`?

Comment: Sometimes it isn't about in what cases it could be nil when it reaches the high level development, but about which cases it could be nil under the hood.

Comment: @Alexander when it is not the main bundle, or `CFBundleIdentifier` is missing

Comment: @Alexander It’s nil for unbundled applications’ main bundles and applications whose info.plist files don’t have an entry for the identifier.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Boy I wrote that 7 years ago, wild how the time passes by. I've since run into both of those case (typo in the Info.plist key name, and unbundled executables). Makes sense! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 14):

It's pretty much the same thing in Swift except the class and method names have been shortened:

```
let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier // return type is String?
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to get it programmatically , you can use below line of code :

Objective-C:

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Swift 3.0:

```
let bundleIdentifier =  Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

Updated for latest swift
It will work for both iOS and Mac apps.

For More Info, Check here :

Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/bundleIdentifier

Comment: hey check for swift3, remove your negative check.