# Which file contents the iOS Bundle ID?

Tags: ios, svn, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to get the iOS Bundle ID, from a project that my mate of work, let in our SVN repository.

I'm not a iOS developer so I don't know where to find it (if is it possible).

And until the answer of: Ask him, just say, I can't do it. He has gone from the job.

So, the question will be:

In which file I can find the iOS Bundle ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bundle ID for an Xcode project is located in the `Info.plist` file witch can be found at `[Your-Project-Name]/Info.plist`

Answer (score 1):

Click projects

Targets >General > Bundle Identifier

Or check `Info.plist`

```
let bundleID = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
```

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897086/obtain-bundle-identifier-programatically-in-swift)