# Getting bundle identifier in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, foundation

I'm trying to get bundleID using app's directory and I'm getting an error:
    EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xd8)

application.directory! is a String

```
let startCString = (application.directory! as NSString).UTF8String //Type: UnsafePointer<Int8>
let convertedCString = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(startCString) //CFURLCreateFromFileRepresentation needs <UInt8> pointer
let length = application.directory!.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let dir = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, convertedCString, length, false)
let bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, dir)
let result = CFBundleGetIdentifier(bundle)
```

and I get this error on the result line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this for the bundle identifier of your own app? Why so complicated? Have a look at [Obtain bundle identifier programatically in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897086/obtain-bundle-identifier-programatically-in-swift).

Comment: It's not. It's a bundle of another app. That is why I'm not using .mainBundle().bundleIdentifier on NSBundle.

Comment: Then what about `NSBundle(path: ...).bundleIdentifier` ?

Comment: What the heck!  Really? That simple? Thank you very (!) much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential problem with your code is that the pointer obtained in

```
let startCString = (application.directory! as NSString).UTF8String //Type: UnsafePointer<Int8>
```

is valid only as long as the *temporary* `NSString` exists. But that
conversion to a C string can be done "automatically" by the compiler
(compare [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior)), so a working version
should be

```
let dir = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, path, Int(strlen(path)), false)
let bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, dir)
let result = CFBundleGetIdentifier(bundle)
```

But you can simply create a `NSBundle`
from a given path and obtain its identifier:

```
let ident = NSBundle(path: path)!.bundleIdentifier!
```

Full example with added error checking:

```
let path = "/Applications/TextEdit.app"

if let bundle = NSBundle(path: path) {
    if let ident = bundle.bundleIdentifier {
        print(ident) // com.apple.TextEdit
    } else {
        print("bundle has no identifier")
    }
} else {
    print("bundle not found")
}
```

Comment: Wow, you even thought about the more complicated (and not necessary) code! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to get it programmatically , you can use below line of code :

Objective-C:

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```

Swift 3.0:

```
let bundleIdentifier =  Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
```

(Updated for latest swift It will work for both iOS and Mac apps.)

For More Info, Check here :

> Apple Docs:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/bundleIdentifier

Comment: Seems like they improved the way it is done! Great news!