# How to get App Groups name programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I am using extensions in my application. For sharing data between app and extension using app Groups. How Can I read App Group name programmatically so no need create extra configuration file for storing App Group name.

Answer (score 3):

You'll only be able to use this in **development** (Debug mode), the `entitlements` are written into the `embedded.mobileprovision` file in the app bundle.

The `embedded.mobileprovision` will not be included when you archive an `.ipa` file or deliver your app to the `AppStore`.

When in `Debug` you can try this:

```
/* Swift 3 */

if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourProjectName", ofType: "entitlements") {
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    let appGroups: NSArray = dict?.object(forKey: "com.apple.security.application-groups") as! NSArray
}
```

Comment: So the app group name will have to be hard-coded for production?

Comment: If you unzip you ipa file, you will get a file named 'embedded.mobileprovision'; the command `security cms -Di embedded.mobileprovision` will tell you the app group name.

Answer (score 1):

So, the correct answer is: It doesn’t work.
Use a static class or constants for your app group names.

Answer (score 1):

The app group name typically is built with the main app's bundle identifier. So, if you're willing to make the assumption that you will prefix it with the standard "group." and perhaps suffix it with ".widget" (for the widget's bundle id) then you can obtain the app group name programmatically by using

```
var appGroupName: String { "group." + bundleIdentifier + ".widget" }
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897086/obtain-bundle-identifier-programmatically-in-swift) shows how to obtain the bundleIdentifier.